# Как считать проценты и числа в python?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне работать с процентами и числами в python. У меня есть переменная `percent = 15` (может быть любое число) и переменная `cost = 500` (может быть любое число), подскажите пожалуйста как отнять от числа процент и убрать цифры после запятой (если будет выходить `413.12312` то делать `413`)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться тем, что в питоне 3.x есть целочисленное деление и обойтись без лишних операций:

```
percent = 15
cost = 500
result = (100 - percent) * cost // 100
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
425
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_cost = int(cost - cost*percent/100)
```